# livecode: android development and export function

Tags: android, file, export, livecode

I am making an app on the android, and for some reason I noticed that the command

```
ask file
```

doesn't work on the android.
I put it in a button and I get no reaction when I test it on the android.
This kinda makes exporting a problem....
Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting isn't very easy on Android due to permissions problems. Apps are sandboxed and most apps only have direct read access to `specialfolderpath("engine")` and direct read and write access to `specialfolderpath("documents")`.

If you want to export text, you can use the put/get URL command to export it to a server or you can use `mobileComposeMail` to send it by e-mail for instance. The mobileComposeMail command can also accept attachments, which allows you to attach a picture or any other data.

To export pictures to the photo album, use `mobileExportImageToAlbum`.